# how to list all the missing series though the count_over_time over a condition is not met

Tags: prometheus, promql

When I run the below, I could see 3 series (out of 5 series in total) which satisfy > 500 condition, but how can I list other 2 series also as 0?

```
count_over_time((some_metric{env="test"} > 500 )[10m:15s])
```

[image: 3 series screenshot]

I expect all 5 series

Comment: add `or some_metric{env="test"}*0`